# why parseargs stores the argument inside a list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, argparse

I have an argparse that is given a string:

```
def f():
    return 'dummy2'

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--a', nargs=1, type=str)
p.add_argument('--b', nargs='?', const=f(), default=f())
p.parse_args('--a dummy'.split())
```

The parser namespace is `Namespace(a=['dummy'], b='dummy2')`.

How can I make the argument for `a` be stored as a string and not as a list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, just skip the argument for `nargs`. Try this:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--a', type=str)
p.add_argument('--b', nargs='?', const=f(), default=f())
```

I believe this is what you expected:

```
p.parse_args('--a dummy'.split())
=> Namespace(a='dummy', b='dummy2')
```

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> ArgumentParser objects usually associate a single command-line argument with a single action to be taken. The nargs keyword argument associates a different number of command-line arguments with a single action. The supported values are:
>
> N (an integer). N arguments from the command line will be gathered together into a list ... Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

Comment: can you explain? I thought `nargs 1` should enforce giving only one argument, basiaclly doing nothing when I suplly my correct string

Comment: ok, nevermind... just saw this ('Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.').

Comment: Yup, it's there in the docs, I updated my answer to reflect it